# C++ Abstract Class - Add needed data member, or just define methods to act on it?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I want to define an Interface class, so that all derived classes have a common ...interface. These are Components, and I have a collection of them. I want to give each of them an ID number, and a Name. Is it better to define the data members in the ABC with accessor methods, and derived classes go through those, or should the ABC simply define the methods that access the data, and each derived class declares it's own ID member?

Answer (score -1):

In this case, I will not have the data member in ABC. Instead just provide methods like `getID()` and `getName()` in ABC and let the derived classes determine whether they actually require a data member to implement these methods.